# How to multi Edit Test Cases to update User Story in Rally?

Tags: rally

I have bunch of test cases existing in Rally and they are not currently tied to User Stories. I want to multi edit set of test cases and mass update User Story against them in single shot. Rally doesn't support Work Product field (user story) to multi edit in Test Case section. It needs each test case to be manually opened and updated with User Story one after another; very time consuming task.

is there any easy solution to solve this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Within the UI this would be easiest to do using a Custom Grid.

1) Go to your dashboard, Select Actions -> Add App

[image: ActionsAddApp]

2) Select the Custom Grid app and then Add this App

[image: AddCustomGrid]

3) Configure the App. Give it a Title, and Select Test Case as the Object type.

[image: ConfigureGrid1]

4) Select additional Columns. Test Folder may be helpful. You'll need to select Work Product in order to Parent the Test Cases to User Stories or Defects. The example also shows a filter query added to show just Test Cases from a particular Test Folder.

[image: ConfigureGrid2]

5) Click Save when done configuring.

6) Select the Test Cases you wish to Parent to a User Story using the check boxes. Then click any of the gear widgets to access the Bulk Actions menu. Select "Choose Work Product..."

[image: BulkChooser]

7) Choose the radio button for the User Story or Defect you wish to make an association for. You can search by keyword, or Filter by Formatted ID and/or Project. Click Choose. when done.

[image: ChooseWorkProduct]

8) Note that Test Cases are Parented to User Story selected.

[image: ParentedTestCases]

9) And can be seen on Story's Details Page:

[image: TestCasesOnStoryDetails]